# Reading .txt file into an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to be able to read a text file into an array instead of inputting all the values myself.
The text file reads as:

8.7
9.3
7.9
6.4
9.6
8.0
8.8
9.1
7.7
9.9
5.8
6.9

The main purpose of the program is to read scores from a data file, store them in an array, and calculate the highest, lowest, total and average of the 12 scores.

The text file is stored in the Debug folder of the project.

This is what I've done so far:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Numbers in the list: " + scores.Length);


        //highest number
        double high = scores[0];

        for (int index = 1; index < scores.Length; index++)
        {
            if (scores[index] > high)
            {
                high = scores[index];
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Highest number = " + high);

        //lowest number
        double low = scores[0];

        for (int index = 1; index < scores.Length; index++)
        {
            if (scores[index] < low)
            {
                low = scores[index];
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("lowest number = " + low);

        //average of the scores
        double total = 0;
        double average = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < scores.Length; index++)
        {
            total = total + scores[index];
        }

        average = (double)total / scores.Length;

        Console.WriteLine("Total = " + total);
        Console.WriteLine("Average = " + average.ToString("N2"));
        Console.ReadKey();



    }
}
```

}

Comment: `var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\scores.txt");`

Comment: `string[]lines=File.ReadAllLines(path);double[] values=Array.ConvertAll(lines, double.Parse);`

Comment: numbers.Min, numbers.Max, numbers.Average. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386914(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `File.ReadLines()` is better than `File.ReadAllLines()` - it won't buffer the entire file in memory.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Gotcha! Now you need to explain what buffering is to the OP. :)

Comment: Hah! Well hopefully he will know what that means. ;) Anyway, this is how I'd do it: `var array = File.ReadLines(@"C:\scores.txt").Select(double.Parse).ToArray();`

Comment: Also more information about LINQ (with samples): http://odetocode.com/articles/739.aspx

Comment: Thank you Matthew, that worked really well. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you all for your input

Answer (score 2):

You have no code in place for reading a file, or writing a file so that will be your problem. I suggest you start with looking at:  [StreamReader Class (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx).

Then you will probably want to look at the following: [String.Split Method (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

To make the program a bit more dynamic you possible want to consider looking at this:

[Application.ExecutablePath Property (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx)

[Enviroment.GetFolderPath Method (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx) (This allows you to store data in better locations)

^^^^Original Response above^^^^^

Another option you could consider is described in a lot of detail here:

[Working with Files - Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819158/Working-with-Files-Using-Csharp-and-NET-Framework)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `File.ReadLines` method to read the lines lazily (means doesn't load all the lines to memory at once) from your file and `Select` method to take each line and parse it to `double`:

```
var values = File.ReadLines("path")
            .Select(line => double.Parse(line))
            .ToArray();
```

Then you can use [`Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347632(v=vs.95).aspx),[`Min`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min(v=vs.95).aspx),[`Average`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average(v=vs.95).aspx) methods from `LINQ` to get highest,lowest number and the average.

Comment: Yep, is good - but note you can simplify the select to `.Select(double.Parse)`

Answer (score 1):

All of this can be writen easier :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

String path = @"MyFolder\myfile.txt"; // path for your file

// read the file
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
// convert data in Doubles    
Double[] data = Array.ConvertAll(lines, Double.Parse);

// use Linq to get what you want (min, max, total, average, ...)
Double low = data.Min();
Double high = data.Max();
Double total = data.Sum();
Double average = data.Average();
```

Answer (score 0):

var scores = File.ReadAllLines("scores.txt").Select(x => Double.Parse(x)).ToArray();

Comment: Doesn't answer the question in full.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\numbers.txt")
                  .Select(n => double.Parse(n));
var max = numbers.Max();
var min = numbers.Min();
var sum = numbers.Sum();
var avg = numbers.Average();
```

Comment: `var min = numbers.Max();`  ? `var sum = numbers.Max();` ?

Comment: @Xaruth Dunno what you mean? Ahem... :)